# How can I get a valueOf generic enum?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an interface with a default method that returns valueOf(string) of that enum or null it there isn't any, so I can easily implement it without needing to paste the non-generic variant of this code in all classes in which I need such thing. So I tried doing this but it doesn't compile:

```
public interface EnumWNull<T extends Enum<T>> {
    default T getEnumOrNull(String value){
        try {
            return Enum.valueOf(T /*Error: expression expected*/, value);
        }catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why. And I actually know I can just read all the values and search for it manually, however I want to know a better way than that for the sake of learning and elegance(and I feel like there should be a better way, if there isn't, what's the purpose of the static variant of valueOf ?).

Comment: [`Enum.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) takes a `Class<T>` as a parameter, not a `T`.

Comment: If it were possible to infer the class from `T`, don't you think `Enum.valueOf()` would have done so, instead of requiring the `Class` token?

Comment: Why have you chosen to approach this problem with an interface with a default method? A static utility method may be preferable here.

Comment: you are trying to pass type T instead of reference to Class of T. hence the error. But wondering why are you doing so.

Comment: Well if I try to cast it into Class<T> I get an info that it is an useless cast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do it without passing a `Class` object. You'll need to mimic the signature of `Enum.valueOf()`:

```
static <T extends Enum<T>> T getEnumOrNull(Class<T> enumType, String name) {
    try {
        return Enum.valueOf(enumType, name);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of implementing an interface with a default method, I suggest creating a static utility method. @shmosel's answer nicely does this, but I suggest using `Optional` to convey that the method can return null (I've forked his code).

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> Optional<T> getEnumValue(Class<T> enumType, String name) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(Enum.valueOf(enumType, name));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is essentially what Guava's [`Enums.getIfPresent()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Enums.html#getIfPresent-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) does.

Answer (score 0):

public static <T extends Enum> T getEnumOrNull(Class enumType, String name) {
return nonNull(name) ? Enum.valueOf(enumType, name) : null;
}